# Azure Devops Extension is no longer loading font file for icons

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-devops-extensions

I've had a custom devops extension published for a few years now and randomly yesterday while making some changes we noticed that the icons do not load anymore. In the console log we see the following warnings

`Failed to decode downloaded font: our_test_server_urls/_apis/public/gallery/publisher/{our_publisher_name}/extension/{extensionId/{extension_version}/assetbyname/dist/94fb5f9747cd4dcd0331.woff2`

`OTS parsing error: invalid sfntVersion: 1836016757`

The changes we've made should not impact our font loading. Additionally I pulled down the production branch and ran that code locally and we get the same errors. But in our actual production extension the icons are loading fine. I really want to push these updates out but if the icons aren't going to load I can't do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be something different with how the .woff2 file is being built using webpack.

Try updating your rule from:

```
{
    test: /\.woff(2)$/,
    use: [{
        loader: 'base64-inline-loader'
    }]
},
```

to:

```
{
    test: /\.woff2?$/i,
    type: 'asset/resource',
    dependency: { not: ['url'] },
}
```

This should fix the icon issue.